# How to make file download from linux folders in php

Tags: linux, php

i have the backup archives in some linux folder.

```
/backups
```

Now i want make the web interface from which user can download those files.

is there any way that that i can have username and password and that user can download that file

Just like in cpanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will let you create the alias so that http://127.0.0.1/backups will work.

```
Alias /backups "/backups"
<Directory "/backups">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

To turn on password prompts, put the following in /backups/.htaccess:

```
[kevin@box backups]$ cat .htaccess
AuthType Basic
AuthName "_password prompt text_"
AuthUserFile /var/www/conf/backup-user-file
AuthGroupFile /var/www/conf/backup-group-file
Require group backup-users
[kevin@box backups]$
```

The backup group file, equivalent to /etc/group, can just be created.

```
[kevin@box choir]$ cat /var/www/conf/backup-group-file
backup-users: backup-user-1 backup-user-2
```

The backup user file must be created using the `htpasswd` utility. The first time you run it, you will need to do so with the `-c`(create a new file) option.

```
[kevin@box backups]$ htpasswd -c /var/www/conf/backup-user-file backup-user-1
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user backup-user-1
[kevin@box backups]$ htpasswd /var/www/conf/backup-user-file backup-user-2
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user backup-user-2
[kevin@box backups]$
```